# Is it okay to run two different graphics card on the same pc?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, compatibility

I'm currently using a 4GiB Nvidia GTX 1050ti on Gigabyte B360M D3H motherboard. I want to add more graphics memory to the system. I would like to buy a 4GiB GTX 1650 graphics card and I'm concerned about the compatibility.

Is it worth to do that upgrade? Will there be any compatibility issues? I'm not going to use two monitors. So is it worth to do that upgrade or do i need a more powerful and bigger graphics card.

Comment: Yes, you can run multiple graphics cards at once.  There might often be some benefit to having both cards be the same model, but that is generally not necessary at all.  I voted to close because a lot of your other questions are vague or off-topic for SuperUser.com.  https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ may be more appropriate, but I suspect even "is it worth" may be inappropriate even there, because StackExchange thrives better on questions with specific factual answers, rather than personal judgement calls which can easily be largely based on opinions.

Comment: Besides the idea that some of these questions might not be super appropriate, there is simply the issue of there being multiple questions.  Ideally, we strive for having just one question in each "question" posted on the site.  Sometimes, multiple questions work well when they are so related that the same factual information is likely to address both questions.  But four questions is typically too much.  It is better to split up the things you wonder about, into multiple posted questions (which can each be individually answered with specific info).

Comment: Graphics memory will not add up so I would suggest to sell the GTX1050ti and buy a more powerful card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graphics memory and performance doesn't sum up.

Some GPUs can run in tandem if you have two identical cards (SLI/CrossFire), but even then it doesn't just give you 2x performance, many games can't utilize dual GPUs.

With 1050 Ti + 1650 you'll have to use one or the other, not both. Keeping both in a PC would only make sense if you'd want to connect more monitors and hit one card's limit.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it does not work that way. Adding a second graphics card is a bit like adding a second car.  It does not make the first car go faster nor does it give it a larger cargo capacity.

A second card makes sense if:

1. If you need more graphics outputs (you already wrote that this is not the case for you)
2. Or you want to do graphics on one of them and use the other for non graphics calculations.
3. Or if you have two very similar versions and can use crossfire/SLI. This will **not** double the speed, nor will it increase usable memory since both cards will have a copy of the data. And the games need to support this, which is not all that common.
4. DirectX 12 seems to be able to leverage a second GPU. (but then your game needs to support dx12)

Usually this means that you are better off with one faster card then with multiple slower cards.

Answer (score 0):

Very basically...
Yes you can run two graphics cards which are not connected via SLi/CrossFire but the configuration you are suggesting would not give you any benefit.
If you want to harness the power of two graphics cards as you are suggesting, then you would have to have two 1050s or two 1650s ad SLi them. This allows the system to harness the "added" memory and processing power from the second card.

Comment: 1050 doesn't support SLI. I don't know about 1650, but it's rather unlikely - in the 10x0 series SLI was possible only with 1070 and 1080.