# My Gaming PC internals

Tags: windows-10

I have a 1660 ti GPU and I was wondering can I use my 1060 ti GPU in the same computer? They both are the same brand of GPU. I have 2 extra GPU slots on my motherboard.

Comment: You can use them but they are not going to work together as a combined graphics card.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it okay to run two different graphics card on the same pc?](https://superuser.com/questions/1512038/is-it-okay-to-run-two-different-graphics-card-on-the-same-pc)

Answer (score 1):

You can, but they cannot be used to both drive one display i.e. SLI.